# css sidebar should scroll vertically when content overflows

Tags: css

How do I need to modify [this example](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/left-sidebar) so that if <s>the</s> its content is longer (in height) than the sidebar, then the sidebar shows the vertical scrollbar?

Thanks

Comment: Have you though of using an iframe?

Comment: I have solved my problem by not having it float, and specifying left, top and bottom: 0px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it like this:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
div#left-sidebar { overflow-y: auto; }
```

hope that's what u wanted